# Applet Error : Authentication Requires

Tags: java, security, authentication, jar, applet

[image: When loading Applet its asking for the Integrated Windows authentication..]

When loading Applet its asking for the Integrated Windows authentication, in the earlier deployments i am not getting these messages. Two days before i created a Applet Jar and deployed in the server(IIS) at that time i dint get any authentication messages. But today i created a new jar with the same source code and deployed in that same server, but i am getting this wizard now .I dont know what is the issue here..

Comment: That image is 2,274px × 962px - ***please crop it in future!***

Comment: I had made some changes in user settings and now it works fine